# can we make curved acrofields using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using itext and want to make my acrofields curved. Say textfield with rounded corners,

and apply the same to buttons and imageField(pustButtonField).

Is it possible in itext or by using some other api.

Thanks in advance for everybody valuable reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're actually asking, there are three possible answers to this question:

1. ISO-32000 only allows you to define a rectangle as the clickable area of AcroForm fields. This is the area that is highlighted when you select *highlight fields*. You can define a border for this rectangle consisting of an array containing at least 3 values: the horizontal corner radius, the vertical corner radius and the border width. An optional fourth value allows you to define the dash pattern.
2. Apart from this you can create any appearance for a widget annotation that corresponds with an AcroForm field. The appearance is stored in the `/AP` entry of the annotation dictionary. This is quite common for button fields (see for instance the `createAppearance()` method in the [Calculator](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=142) example). This is *not done* for text fields, as the appearance will disappear the moment somebody changes the value of the text field.
3. Maybe you are asking to create a rectangular border that is part of the content stream of the page as opposed to a shape that is defined at the AcroField level (see for instance how Open Office adds border to form fields: these borders don't disappear when you remove the field dictionary).

If I had to guess, I'd say you're looking for answer 2 regarding buttons and for answer 3 regarding text fields.

**Update:** thank you for accepting the answer even though I misunderstood the question. You were asking for a field where you define a path (not necessarily a straight line) that will be used to position the value of the field (for instance: a word written in a way that the characters form a circle). That's not possible with AcroForm fields.

Comment: actually i am looking for first answer i.e i want my text acrofield to be in some arc shape instead of simple rectangular shape and when i write text the text or complete line of text will also form the arc shape. But i think it seems to be impossible.

Comment: Aha, that's not possible with AcroForm annotations. Nevertheless, my answer wasn't complete. I'll update it.